# Metaphorisches Äquivalent für „Eine Maus darf nicht an den Schnurrhaaren der Katze ziehen“

Tags: translation, proverb

Ich suche ein deutsches Äquivalent für dieses ungarische Sprichwort:

> Eine Maus darf nicht an den Schnurrhaaren der Katze ziehen.

Das bedeutet, dass man in einer verwundbaren Situation keine riskante Sachen tun darf.

Zum Beispiel sollte man, wenn man schon genug Punkte in Flensburg hat, besonders vorsichtig fahren, um seinen Führerschein nicht zu verlieren.

Comment: @Jan Wenn ich doch die Edits auch upvoten könnte :-) Danke sehr!

Comment: Aus [tag:english-to-german] schließe ich, daß es ein englisches Vorbild gibt – wie lautet das?

Comment: @chirlu Nein, das kam nicht aus englisch, sonst ungarisch. Vielleicht ein any-to-german Tag wäre nützlicher, ich denke, meist solche Fragen kommen nicht von englischen Muttersprächler.

Comment: @Jan: _Punkte in Flensburg_ ist aber sehr deutschlandspezifisch …

Comment: _Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Porzellankiste._

Comment: @Crissov Das wäre eine gute Antwort!

Comment: *Den Ast absägen, auf dem man sitzt* geht auch in die Richtung, ist aber etwas drastischer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ein Äquivalent mit einem anderen Tier:

> Schlafende Hunde soll man nicht wecken.

Ebenfalls ähnlich ist dieses Sprichwort:

> Wer im Glashaus sitzt, soll nicht mit Steinen werfen.

Comment: Wer im Glashaus sitzt, soll im Keller kacken gehen.

Comment: @Robert: Bei der Variante geht es aber um Privatsphäre, nicht um Gefahren.

Comment: Bewohner transparenter Behausungen sollten im höchsteigenen Interesse ballistische Experimente mit mineralischen Körpern tunlichst unterlassen.